# Invariance of vector fields under diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two diffeomorphisms of some smooth manifold $M$ to itself. Say $X$ is a left-invariant vector field of $\phi$. This means $\phi_{*}X=X$.

Does it mean $X$ is also a left-invariant vector field of $\psi$ as well (or $\psi_{*}X=X$)? Basically, I want to know if the left-invariant property is specific to a certain diffeomorphism or if the set of left-invariant vector fields is specific to some smooth manifold.

I also would like to know the answer to the same question for the special case, that $M$ is a Lie group.

Comment: Consider two rotations of the sphere about different axes, and what it means to be invariant under each of them.

Comment: If we take $\phi = \operatorname{id}_M$, an affirmative answer would imply that every vector field $X$ satisfies $\psi_* X = X$ for every diffeomorphism $\psi$ of $M$, which certainly can't be true.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider the special case that $\phi$ is the identity $\operatorname{id}_M$: Every vector field $X$ satisfies $({\operatorname{id}_M})_* X = X$, but not every vector field satisfies $\psi_* X = X$ for every diffeomorphism $\psi$ of $M$.

For a concrete example (already in dimension $1$), take $$M = \Bbb R, \qquad X = \partial_x, \qquad\phi : x \mapsto x, \qquad \psi : x \mapsto -x .$$ Computing directly gives that $$\phi_* X = X \qquad \textrm{but} \qquad \psi_*X = -X .$$ (Note that the result is the same even if we replace $\phi$ with the nonidentity diffeomorphism $x \mapsto x + 1$.)